# Group-variables not being recognized by Ansible

Tags: ansible

My host file contains a group like so:

```
[api_dev:vars]
private_key_file=/opt/keys/api_dev.pem
```

Though when I try pinging the server:

```
ansible api_dev -m ping -vvvv
```

I see that the private key file isn't being used.

In addition, I have also tried creating group_var files in      /etc/ansible/group_vars and then specifying the key like this:

```
---
private_key_file: /opt/keys/api_dev.pem
```

Still with no luck.

I'm looking at the information on: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

Am I missing something? or is there a hierarchy that I'm completely ignoring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Argh.

Ubuntu repo's currently have version 1.9 as latest. For version <2 use the key as:

```
ansible_ssh_private_key_file:
```

Hope this helps someone!